# Ugly Number problem using dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm

I am learning Dynamic Programming and tried to solve the [nth ugly number](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugly-numbers/) problem using it. Here's my code for the problem in Java:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class UglyNum {
    //using DP bottom up
    public static int getUgly(int n) {
        HashSet<Integer> u = new HashSet<>();
        if (n < 6)
            return n;
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            u.add(i);
        }
        int x = 5;
        int i = 6;
        boolean flag;
        while (x < n) {
            flag = false;
            flag = checkContains(i, 2, u, flag);
            if(!flag)
            flag = checkContains(i, 3, u, flag);
            if(!flag)
            flag = checkContains(i, 5, u, flag);
            if (flag) {
                u.add(i);
                x++;
            }
            if (x == n)
                return i;
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }


    private static boolean checkContains(int x, int n, HashSet<Integer> u, boolean flag) {
        if (x % n == 0) {
            if (u.contains(x / n))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
    //DP ends here

}
```

The idea is that a new number, say x, is ugly only if x/2 or x/3 or x/5 is ugly.

I analysed the code wrt the 2 codes given in the  GFG site article and here are the results for 100 ugly numbers:
[image]

The first time (26.3992 ms) is the time using my dynamic programming approach. The other 2 are the ones given on the site. Clearly my program is taking relatively too much time. Can you help me optimise it?

PS: I am aware of the [awesome methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600048/nth-ugly-number) to solve the problem but wondering why mine is so slow.

Comment: *"Clearly my program is taking too much time"* - No, that's not clear at all. What makes you think so? Too much for what?

Comment: @superbrain it's 8 times more than the GFG DP approach

Comment: But why is that too much?

Comment: It's **relatively** high.

Comment: And could it be that that's just because it's the first one and Java, the process or the CPU aren't running at top speed yet? Can't test this myself, as you only show part of the program.

Comment: @superbrain I copy-pasted the java code for both from GFG. printed the 100 values and recorded the time using System.nanoTime();. Secondly, my code takes more time than the non-DP approach which indicates it's bad.

Comment: Well now you make it sound like you're even including the printing time in the time. Can't tell, as you don't show the code. When I run it on repl.it (which is probably slower than your PC), it takes about 2.5 ms. And why shouldn't the non-DP approach be faster? You're only testing small numbers.

Comment: @superbrain The point is that printing is included for all, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @superbrain here's the code with two DP versions and the tester: https://paste.ofcode.org/ThEbngYZdSx3r5VZxKpJmD

Comment: This time I compared my DP with the approach illustrated in this medium article: https://medium.com/@interviewprep/ugly-number-dynamic-programming-94520110a084#:~:text=The%20algorithm%20is%20straightforward%3A%20choose,ll%20have%20n%20ugly%20numbers.

Comment: The idea with this problem is, that you should spot the similarity to the sieve of erastosthenes. Starting from 1 and marking n * 2, n * 3 and n * 5 for each marked number will only perform 3 multiplications. Checking backwards for a factor will perform up to three modulo operations and in your code up to three divisions on top. Both of these operations as *much* slower than multiplications.